# Add favorite tags on site X to tag filter

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, tag-watching, tag-filters

The tag filters on stackexchange.com allow users to either add specific tags on a site (or all of them) or all questions on a specific site to the filter. There is also a fixed filter that shows all favorites from all sites.

What I'd like to do is to add my favorites from a specific site to a filter, without having to manually reproduce my favorite tags from the site in the tag filter. There should be an additional option

> I'd like to include...
>
> - questions from my favorite tags

in addition to the existing options

> I'd like to include...
>
> - All Questions
> - Just questions tagged with the ________________  tag

This would make it far easier to create a filter that shows me all questions from my low-volume site and only my favorite tags from the higher volume sites.