# Allow adding only the favorite tags from a specific site to a tag filter

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, tag-watching, tag-filters

There is a "Favorite Tags" filter that everyone gets on stackexchange.com. It's not quite as useless as the other default filter "My Sites" that shows all questions on all sites you have an account on, but it's close for many user. For example, I have some favorite tags on Stack Overflow, and due to the vast differences in traffic it means that my "Favorite Tags" filter essentially contains only SO questions, with the occasional question from another site thrown in. Low traffic sites are completely drowned out.

Of course you can create custom filters, but then you have to define each site and/or each tag individually. The tag filter dialog looks like this:

[image]

So I could add only a few tags from some sites, and I've done so. But I then have to remember to change this filter every time I get interested in a new tag.

It would be much easier if instead of adding an entire site, or adding a single tag of a site, I could add my favorites of a single site to a tag filter. That way the filters would automatically change when I change my favorite tags and I wouldn't have to manually update them. And I could still exclude high-traffic sites like SO that would otherwise dominate the feed.

Comment: I just discovered that this feature request is a duplicate... of [your own feature request for the same thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122083/335251) from 5 years earlier :P Not sure which should be closed as a duplicate of which.

Comment: @V2Blast Hmm, I've done that at least one other time ;-). Sometimes I forget which feature requests I actually posted and which ones I only thought about. I think this one has more detail, so maybe close the older one as a duplicate

Comment: Makes sense. I've closed the other as a dupe now :)